# WPF Autocomplete using Combobox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create an autocomplete textbox in WPF. What i found is http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx. It seems quite close to what i needed. The only thing missing in this is when i press down arrow key after typing some characters it does not allow to me select an item from the narrowed list in dropdown.

Please give me some pointers how can i allow to select item using up/down keys after filtering list using some text input.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been many implementations already for an autocompletebox. So as swiszcz stated, look for a working & well documented project. You need not spend time on trying to tweak some particular code for too long, when other options are available.

I have used an [AutoCompleteBox implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx) by **Aviad P** for many projects and found it easy enough to tweak and suite my needs. I feel the code is well documentated in the blog article itself. Also it uses a textbox & listbox (rather than a combobox) which is in my opinion, a better choice.

Comment: seems like there is no option of creating an autocomplete using combo box right away. i will take a look at it.